# Relative and Absolute Path in Python Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, path

I have succesfully, seperated my settings file to Development and Production settings.

While trying to import from base (common to the two) I always get path error.

[image: File Structure]

When I try to do this in prod.py file

`from src.psm_website.settings.base import *`

and try to compile with the IDE, it works well ( I used a print statement to print from a variable from the base file)

But when I try to deploy to Heroku, I get the error

```
from src.psm_website.settings.base import *
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
remote:
```

Then when I change the import statement to this

```
from .base import *
```

I get this error when trying to deploy in heroku

```
raise KeyError(key) from None
remote:        KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

Secret key is a variable in base file, meaning base was not imported

and I get this error when I try to run from  the IDE.

```
from .base import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have **init**.py in all parent directory, making them pakages from what I have read.

How can I solve this

Python Version: 3.7.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **don't** want "src" to be a python package, only your apps and your project directory ("psm_website" in your case) should be, so first of all remove any `__init__.py` file from your "src" directory (and any parent directory). Python will lookup packages/modules in directories (not "packages" - just directories **containaing** packages) listed in it's `sys.path`, which by default should already begin with your current working directory.

Then you just reference the package or module by it's python qualified name, in your case `from psm_website.settings.base import *`. Just note that you'll have to properly set your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` envvar to point to the appropriate setting file, ie `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=psm_website.settings.prod` etc.

NB: if you have *any* python import or setting using a python qualified path starting with "src", by all mean fix it, else you're almost garanteed to get [double import](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap) issues (been here, done that...).